# Prioritizing packet in mininet

Tags: python, sdn

I am new to mininet and I need to create a mininet topology which sends packets with some packets having higher priority than others, and then show packet flooding on it. Any tutorials on how to prioritize packets?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well I made the topology but I am having problem  on prioritizing the packets